# Приемлю, приемлешь

Tags: этимология

К какому времени (настоящему или будущему) исторически относились следующие словоформы и почему: приемлю, приемлешь, приемлет, приемлем, приемлете, приемлют?

Пример:

иже аще прииметъ отроча се въ имя мое, мене приемлетъ.

Comment: Задать вопрос к словоформам не пробовали? Как учат в четвертом классе.

Comment: ну и какой же вопрос Вас учили задавать в школе? Заметьте, что у данных словоформ отсутствует суффикс "а"

Comment: А вот не надо этих иже аще. Вас тоже учили.

Answer (score 2):

```
 К какому времени (настоящему или будущему) 
 исторически относились следующие словоформы и 
 почему: приемлю, приемлешь, приемлет,
 приемлем, приемлете, приемлют?
```

Настоящее время - исходное.

Особое образование форм будущего времени, представленное в истории некоторых индоевропейских языков, было утрачено славянскими языками давно. Не отразились эти формы и в старославянских памятниках. Уже в праславянском языке будущее время передавалось другими способами.

В старославянском языке значение действия, которое будет происходить в будущем, могло выражаться при помощи глаголов в форме настоящего времени. Глаголы настоящего времени, употребленные в значении будущего времени, могли быть как совершенного, так и несовершенного вида (ср. русск: Завтра я иду на работу). Значение будущего времени, не связанное непосредственно с видовыми различиями, определялось контекстом:
http://tezaurus.oc3.ru/docs/1/articles/3/3/5/

Будущее время глагола идёт параллельно с развитием категории вида.

Из праслав. языка ДРЯ унаследовал  2 формы буд.вр. – простое буд. и слож. буд. время. Развитие форм буд. простого намечается еще в праслав. языке на базе наст. вр. Формы глаг. СВ с приставками в наст. вр. сост. простое буд.вр. Глаголы с приставкой обозначают действие в будущем. По мере образования вида идет размежевание наст./буд.вр.

Глаголы СВ образуют будущее простое, а глаг. НСВ образуют наст.вр. и будущее сложное.
Не ~демъ (не поедем) ни на конихъ ни на возhхъ.

В др-рус. период простое буд. вр. находилось в стадии формирования,  а с окончательным противопоставлением СВ / НСВ формируется простое буд. время. Формы и окончания как у наст. времени.

Так что вопрос Ваш коварен: Вы имеете в виду, что с приставкой - будущее время? Но ведь здесь ещё и вопрос об основах совершенного и несовершенного вида. Нужно и с этим разбираться - что раньше, что позже (у меня на это времени нет). Есть, видимо, различие и в развитии грамматических  категорий  в ДРЯ и ст.-славянском.

Может, здесь ещё связано с исчезновением формы имать, этот глагол теперь без приставки не употребляется, может, основы сов. и несов. вида разошлись. Так что в одно время это был глагол наст. времени, в другое - будущего, а что первично вот в этом виде - приемлет - ещё неизвестно.

(имать - имаю, емлю; имет, приимет, емлет, приемлет)

Answer (score 1):

ПРИЯ́ТЬ, буд. вр. не употр.; -ял, -яла; -явший; -ятый; совер., кого (что) (стар.). То же, что принять (в 1 знач.).
| несовер. ***приимать, приемлю, приемлешь*** (неопред. не употр., личные формы книжн.). *Не приемлет лжи, компромиссов кто-н*.
| сущ. приятие, -я, ср. (устар. и высок.).

Толковый словарь Ожегова. С.И. Ожегов, Н.Ю. Шведова. 1949-1992.

Я так поняла, что формы будущего времени у глаголов *приемлешь, приемлют* нет.

Comment: Формы есть, но они выходят за рамки современной литературной нормы.

Comment: а может у него наоборот, исторически форма настоящего времени отсутствует?

Comment: @prostorech, прiемлетъ переводится как принимает, глагол употреблён в форме наст.времени: "....и и́же а́ще прiи́метъ отроча́ таково́ во и́мя мое́, мене́ прiе́млетъ - и кто примет одно такое дитя во имя Мое, тот Меня принимает".

Comment: Синодальный перевод, это безусловно святое писание, но оно с точки зрения перевода не безупречно. Например в нем переводится, что Каин и Авель принесли жертву, тогда как в септуагинте написано, что Каин принес дар, а Авель жертву, извините

Comment: быть может, данный глагол исторически аналогичен глаголу финишировать?

Comment: это сугубо мое личное мнение

Comment: Может быть. Прекрасно вас понимаю, но найти ответ-решение очень трудно. Одно могу сказать: это интересно.